# Why does using keep_if in Ruby skip over the first element in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
def unique(arr)
  return arr.keep_if { |x| arr.count(x) == 1 }
end

print unique([2, 5, 5, 4, 22, 8, 2, 8])
#=> [4, 22, 2]
```

The value 2 appears twice in the array, but using the following method incorrectly returns it. Why does that happen, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: If you were Matz, how would you implement `Array#keep_if`?

Comment: Because after you have removed the first `2`, there is only one `2` left, so when you encounter the second `2`, the condition is `true`. Mutable state strikes again.

Comment: @JörgWMittag if that's the case, why are 5 and 8 not also returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is due to some hidden behavior in how `keep_if` works. To illustrate this behavior, we can make use of the lowest-hanging fruit in our debugging orchard, good ol' `puts`:

```
def unique(arr)
  return arr.keep_if { |x| 
    puts x, arr.join(',')
    arr.count(x) == 1
  }
end

print unique([2, 5, 5, 4, 22, 8, 2, 8])
```

This gives us the following as output:

```
2
2,5,5,4,22,8,2,8
5
2,5,5,4,22,8,2,8
5
2,5,5,4,22,8,2,8
4
2,5,5,4,22,8,2,8
22
4,5,5,4,22,8,2,8
8
4,22,5,4,22,8,2,8
2
4,22,5,4,22,8,2,8
8
4,22,2,4,22,8,2,8
[4, 22, 2]
```

Look carefully at exactly what happens whenever the method discovers a new value it wants to keep: it stores that value in one of the early indexes in the array, overwriting what's already there. The next time it finds a value it wants to keep, it places it in the next spot, and so on.

This means that the first time `keep_if` looks at `2`, it sees two of them and so decides to skip it. But it then sees a `4` that it wants to keep, and *overwrites the first `2`*. Thus, the second time it sees a `2`, it decides to keep it.

Comment: Then why isn't the 5 kept as well, since one of its values was overwritten by the 22?

Comment: because it wasn't overwitten until _after_ 5 had been considered

Comment: @ChristopherByrd I believe it's because it's already passed both 5s by the time that happens.

Comment: I would like to second what Holger Just says below; a `select` is probably what you actually want

Answer (score 1):

You are changing an array while you iterate over it. This is [considered undefined behavior](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/23633) by Matz himself and you should avoid doing it if you want to avoid strange behavior like the one you see there.

Instead of your `keep_if` method, you should use this instead:

```
arr.select{ |x| arr.count(x) == 1 }
```

This won't change the array in place but will return a new one however.

Comment: Your first sentence is too strong. `arr = [1,2,3]; arr.map! { |n| 2*n }` changes `arr` as you iterate over it, but it is not undefined behaviour. We know generally what you mean--deleting elements from (or inserting elements into) the array, but you should be more precise.

Comment: Actually, in this case, you are iterating over it (`count`) while you are changing it (`keep_if`) ;-) Which is why this question is even more subtle than the somewhat well-known problems of changing the array while iterating.